# Error on creating button listener first android app

Tags: java, android

As this is my first android app; i couldn't figure out what goes wrong.

**Error**

Error on line "caller.textView.setText(“You clicked the button!”);"

Multiple markers at this line

- Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete 
   Assignment
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete BlockStatements
- Line breakpoint:MyOnClickListener [line: 12] - onClick(View)
- setText cannot be resolved or is not a field

[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A0Ll.png)

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstandroidapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new MyOnClickListener(this));
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**MyOnClickListener.java**

```
package com.example.myfirstandroidapp;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    MainActivity caller;
    public MyOnClickListener(MainActivity activity) {
    this.caller = activity;
    }
    public void onClick(View view) {
    caller.textView.setText(“You clicked the button!”);
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why are ur quotes like that? ` “ ” ` Not sure if it's makes a difference

Comment: This must be a problem with your quotes. Both files are in the same package, so `TextView` is visible inside `OnClickListener`. Imported your project and everything exept quotes is working.

Comment: Solved: Just use quotes 'You clicked the button!'. But, it does not work. Again switch back to " " quotes and then solved itself.